# adding a small image to a image slider caption with bxslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

Using bxslider for a little sliding gallery. I want to show captions, which I realize is built in. But...what I'd also like to do is add a small image to the caption.

This is someone elses fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2L9P/3/

It uses span's to display multiple lines of text in the caption:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg"/>
        <div class="caption1"> 
            <span>Image 1</span><br></br>
            <span>j;jkljlk</span>
            <div class="caption2"><a id="img1a" href="#">Visit Australia</a></div>
        </div>
    </li>
.
.
.
```

But if you stick a img tag in, it just displays as text. How can I put images in the caption?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added image with no problem

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2L9P/4/)

```
<div class="caption1"> 
   <img src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/861/tweet_my_web/128/single_bird.png" />
   <span>j;jkljlk</span>
   <div class="caption2"><a id="img1a" href="#">Visit Australia</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huh...well, whadyaknow. Must have made a type. Didn't seem to work for me earlier. Thanks!